# Making subtags dependent on an attribute of a parent in XML Schema

Tags: xsd

I have created an XML file like the following

```
  <monitor>
    <widget name="Widgets/TestWidget1">
        <state code="VIC" />
        <state code="TAS" />
    </widget>
    <widget name="Widgets/TestWidget2">
        <client code="someclient" />
    </widget>
  </monitor>
```

The name attribute of the `<widget>` tag tells the parser what widget to load (they are asp.net user controls).

I am trying to create a schema file for the above, the problem is that inside the `<widget>` the supported subtags are dependent on the name attribute.  So TestWidget1 supports the `<state>` tag and TestWidget2 supports the `<client` tag.

Currently my XML Schema file just displays all possible `<widget>` subtags regardless of whether they are supported or not.

How can I write an XML schema file that will only allow specific subtags based on the name attribute?  If this is not possible, what options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.  The simplest and most direct is to re-think your problem a bit.  If the legal content of element E1 and the legal content of element E2 are different, then the simplest design is to call them different things, because in XSD as in DTDs the legal content of an element depends on the element type name.  A devil's advocate would ask you "if you want different kinds of widget to obey different rules, why are you telling the validator that they are the same kind of widget?  Tell the validator the truth, by giving them different names.  So don't call them  and so on, call them  and ."

In XSD 1.1 you can also use conditional type assignment or assertions to define constraints on the legal combinations of attributes and children, but not every schema-aware editor is going to have the chops necessary to analyse the conditional type assignment rules and attributes and understand what to prompt you with.